# Проблема с созданием переключателя языков

Tags: html, css

На сайте WordPress необходимо создать выпадающий список переключения языков.
Для перевода используется плагин qtranslate x.

Нужно что бы выглядело вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но плагин позволяет выводить языки только вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первом скрине переключатель реализован с помощью java script. Вопрос, как реализовать переключатель как на первом скрине используя только html и css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: italic;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  background: #ddd;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 40px;
}

.list {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 0px;
}

.list:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 1px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-width: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.list:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.list>li:hover>.sub-list {
  display: block;
}

.sub-list {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item">ENG
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li class="sub-item">ES</li>
          <li class="sub-item">PT</li>
          <li class="sub-item">ID</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А подскажи еще плиз, как теперь сделать что бы при открытии списка,блок main не растягивался вниз, а что бы растягивался только сам список?

Comment: @NewbieUser, вы хотите чтобы блок .main был с фиксированной высотой?

Comment: блок main используется лишь для наглядного примера(центр экрана), можете его не использовать. Если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его решением, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Блок main, будет находиться в шапке сайта, рядом с кнопками логина и регистрации. В вашем примере, когда список с языками раскрывается вниз, он растягивает с собой блок в котором находятся кнопки реги и входа, а так же меню.

А мне нужно что бы при раскрытии списка c языками, НЕ растягивалась вместе с ним шапка сайта.

Мне кажется это что-то с z-index нужно шаманить, но как это сделать к сожалению не знаю.